# Better performance option than find_in_set

Tags: mysql

Currently my code is:

```
Find_in_set(beerkezes, (SELECT Group_concat(beerkezes ORDER BY beerkezes
                                  ASC)
                           FROM   versenyzo as x
                           WHERE  beerkezes <> '00:00:00'
                                  AND v.tav = x.tav AND `szuletesidatum`<`zarodate` AND `szuletesidatum`>`kezdodate` AND v.nem=x.nem))
```

I need to get the rank of the row in the subquery based on the 'beerkezes' column. Preferably with the use of indexes, etc.
Ty.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL 8.0 you could use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY x.nem, x.tav ORDER BY beerkezes) AS rn
FROM   versenyzo as x
WHERE  beerkezes <> '00:00:00'
  AND `szuletesidatum`<`zarodate` 
  AND `szuletesidatum`>`kezdodate`
```